# How to concatenate year(numeric var) and month(character var) as a numeric value on x axis data in scatter plot in sas

Tags: sas

I am trying to make a scatterplot of lead enter image description heretime(numeric variable) versus date, while date is separated into year(numeric var) and month(character variable). However, scatter plot can only set two var in sas. I dont know how to concatenate them into one numeric variable.

```
PROC SGPLOT DATA=hw9.q3;
    scatter Y=LeadTime X = arrivaldatemonth;
RUN;
```

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Why?   Why not just convert YEAR and MONTH into an actual DATE and use a format to display it in whatever style you want?

Answer (score 1):

Compute a SAS date value and use that in your scatter plot.

```
arrival_datestr = catx('-', '01', arrivalMonth, arrivalYear);
arrival_date = input(datestr, anydtdte20.);
format arrival_date yymon7.;
```